# How to resize height & width of the view using constraints for different screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I am very new to xocde 6 & autolayout.I am designing screens for multilple devices.I have some views such as images,textfields.I have desgined them for iPhone.I have added some fix height & width constraints.So height & width remian fix for all devices.I want to change the height & width of the view acrding to screen size.I have tried one method which was

1. make width equal to parent view & give multiplier 0.5.
2. keep height fix.
3. give aspect ratio.

This way view was aligned but it height was fixed.I have also used leading space,trailing space but in this way sometimes unexpected results are achieved.So is there any better way of doing it? I am really having hard time figuring it out.

Comment: Take a look at Adaptive Layout Tutorial: Getting Started http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Comment: TechChain please my update answer.

Answer (score 3):

## 2023 and Later

I highly suggest you use **[SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/)**, it's super easy to use and also super fast results. I can't even compare it to other options. SwiftUI helps you build great-looking apps across all Apple platforms with the power of Swift — and surprisingly little code. You can bring even better experiences to everyone, on any Apple device, using just one set of tools and APIs.

SwiftUI uses a declarative syntax, so you can simply state what your user interface should do. For example, you can write that you want a list of items consisting of text fields, then describe alignment, font, and color for each field. Your code is simpler and easier to read than ever before, saving you time and maintenance.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AlbumDetail: View {
    var album: Album

    var body: some View {
        List(album.songs) { song in 
            HStack {
                Image(album.cover)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(song.title)
                    Text(song.artist.name)
                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This declarative style even applies to complex concepts like animation. Easily add animation to almost any control and choose a collection of ready-to-use effects with only a few lines of code. At runtime, the system handles all of the steps needed to create a smooth movement, even dealing with user interaction and state changes mid-animation. With animation this easy, you’ll be looking for new ways to make your app come alive.

##### Works with UIKit and AppKit

SwiftUI is designed to work alongside UIKit and AppKit, so you can adopt it incrementally in your existing apps. When it’s time to construct a new part of your user interface or rebuild an existing one, you can use SwiftUI while keeping the rest of your codebase.
And if you want to use an interface element that isn’t offered in SwiftUI, you can mix and match SwiftUI with UIKit and AppKit to take advantage of the best of all worlds.

[image: visionOS Hello World Muhammed Gurhan Yerlikaya]

### SwiftData

SwiftData makes it easy to persist data using declarative code. You can query and filter data using regular Swift code. And it’s designed to integrate seamlessly with SwiftUI. SwiftData uses the proven storage architecture of Core Data, so you can use both in the same app with the same underlying storage. When you’re ready, Xcode can convert your Core Data models into classes for use with SwiftData.

### Resources

- Start with [this SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)
- Learning SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts
- wwdc2021/10022 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/
- Sample-Apps https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/Sample-Apps
- Food Truck: Building a SwiftUI multiplatform app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/food_truck_building_a_swiftui_multiplatform_app
- Fruta: Building a Feature-Rich App with SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui
- A visionOS Hello World https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionOS/World
- SwiftData https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftdata/
- Documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/

[image]

##### My Old Answer

If you're new, just for alternative I suggest you to use PureLayout. You can use in your project with cocoapods or Carthage. With this library you can super easily make this constraints for different screens. There is a example project in github project where you can find many different scenarios in. Here is the github page of project :

https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout

Here is some example code snippet for you @deepak kumar :

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    if (!self.didSetupConstraints) {
        // Apply a fixed height of 50 pt to two views at once, and a fixed height of 70 pt to another two views
        [@[self.redView, self.yellowView] autoSetViewsDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:50.0];
        [@[self.blueView, self.greenView] autoSetViewsDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:70.0];
        
        NSArray *views = @[self.redView, self.blueView, self.yellowView, self.greenView];
        
        // Match the widths of all the views
        [views autoMatchViewsDimension:ALDimensionWidth];
        
        // Pin the red view 20 pt from the top layout guide of the view controller
        [self.redView autoPinToTopLayoutGuideOfViewController:self withInset:20.0];
        
        // Loop over the views, attaching the left edge to the previous view's right edge,
        // and the top edge to the previous view's bottom edge
        [[views firstObject] autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft];
        UIView *previousView = nil;
        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if (previousView) {
                [view autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:previousView];
                [view autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:previousView];
            }
            previousView = view;
        }
        [[views lastObject] autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight];
        
        self.didSetupConstraints = YES;
    }
    
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

I believe, if you could start now, it'll be easier for you to pass auto layout headache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to ask, but it sounds like an *Auto Layout* question, if you don't want your *Text View* to fill up the entire screen, go ahead and ***select*** the *Text View* in your **Main.storyboard** and click the ***Pin*** button, like so:

[image]

Notice that all of the constraints are enabled, which means this text view will pin to the edges of your iOS screen.

If you want to later edit those constrains, go ahead and go to the *Size Inspector*, and you can directly click on the constrains:

[image]

Comment: Well i am trying to ask is how can i change the width & height of view for different screen phone in ios. Example i have width=20 & height=20 of a button.it looks fine on 4 inch screen but on iPad this will look very small so i want to change the height & width in equal proportion so that it does not look odd. @Justin

Comment: That's where *Auto Layout* will come into play, something similar to what we did above, check out this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: There is nothing like for multiple devices support.They are just one devices & rotating it.

Comment: That's the point of *Auto Layout*, it *automatically* resizes to the device you run on. @deepakkumar

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. But as you say above "I don't want to code", so why should we help you?